# Cloning independent instance

Tags: c#, clone

The result of this code is "1" and "2". When i split Foo "a" it makes an instance "b" and everything what i do to "b", it happens to "a" too.
Is there any solution to give back a compleatly independent instance of Foo? So the result of my code would be "1" and "1".

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        Baar b0 = new Baar();
        Baar b1 = new Baar();
        Baar b2 = new Baar();
        Baar b3 = new Baar();
        Foo a = new Foo(200);
        a.addBaar(b0);

        Console.WriteLine(a.baars.Count);
        Foo b = a.split(100);

        b.addBaar(b1) ;      
        Console.WriteLine(a.baars.Count);

    }
}

class Foo
{
    public int amount;
    public List<Baar> baars = new List<Baar>();
    public Foo(int amount)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    private Foo(int amount, List<Baar> baars)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.baars = baars;
    }

    public void addBaar(Baar baar)
    {
        this.baars.Add(baar);

    }

    public Foo split(int amount)
    {
        int diff = this.amount - amount;
        this.amount = amount;
        return new Foo(diff, this.baars);
    }
}

class Baar
{

    public Baar()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: "The result of this code is "1" and "2". `...` So the result of my code would be "1" and "2"." -- is one of those a typo, or does your code already do what you want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deep cloning objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)

Comment: yes it was a typo. lol. i have corrected it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `split` method is passing around a reference to the *same* underlying `baars` list. This can be demonstrated simply with:

```
List<int> a = new List<int>();
a.Add(1);

Console.WriteLine(a.Count); //1

List<int> b = a;
b.Add(2);

Console.WriteLine(b.Count); //2
Console.WriteLine(a.Count); //2
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)); //true
```

Instead, you want to pass a *copy* of that list:

```
public Foo split(int amount)
{
    int diff = this.amount - amount;
    this.amount = amount;
    List<Baar> baarsCopy = new List<Baar>(this.baars); //make a copy
    return new Foo(diff, baarsCopy); //pass the copy
}
```

EDIT: Beyond that, I don't know if you want to make copies of the `Baar` items inside that list as well or pass around/share references to the same `Baar` instances. That's up to you and your application usage.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are talking about "deep cloning" objects. That question has been answered plenty of times already.

[How do you do a deep copy of an object in .NET (C# specifically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)

[Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)